# Prove that $\lim_{y\to 0^+} \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\frac{ \lvert \sin(yt)\rvert}{y}} \frac{1}{1+t^2}~dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+t^2}~dt.$

Tags: analysis

(a) Let $R > 0$. Prove that $f(t) = \frac{\sin(yt)}{y}$ converges uniformly to $g(t) = t$ when $y\to 0^+$ on $[0,R]$.

(b) Prove that
$\lim_{y\to 0^+} \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\frac{ \lvert \sin(yt)\rvert}{y}} \frac{1}{1+t^2}~dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+t^2}~dt.$

(c) Let $a,b\in(0,1)$. Prove that the limit
$\lim_{y\to 0^+} \int_0^\infty \frac{y^a\lvert \sin x\rvert^b}{x^2+y^2}~dx$
is finite if and only if $a+b \geq 1$.

I'm reviewing this problem from a Real Analyis test I took last year. I got some points on it, but honestly, I'm kinda confused. First, I'm confused about the notion of uniform convergence in part (a), I thought this is usually only defined for sequences of functions? How is it being defined here? Is this standard?

In part (b), I wrote that from uniform convergence of $\sqrt{\frac{ \lvert \sin(yt)\rvert}{y}} \frac{1}{1+t^2}$ to $\frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+t^2}$ you can get that     $\lim_{y\to 0^+} \int_0^R \sqrt{\frac{ \lvert \sin(yt)\rvert}{y}} \frac{1}{1+t^2}~dt = \int_0^R \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+t^2}~dt$, if you accept the rearrangement of limits and integrals under this setting of uniform convergence. But then how do you pass to $R\to\infty$?

Part (c) I have no idea how to approach at all.

Any clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: The idea of "uniformity" still applies. Uniform means that whatever $\delta$ you are using only depends on $\epsilon$ with no mention of any specific $t$ on the interval $[0,R]$. Each $t$ has the same one-size-fits-all $\delta$ given an $\epsilon$, hence "uniform".

Comment: The (standard) definition of uniform convergence $f_y(t)\to g(t)$ for $t\in E$ as $y\to y_0$ is:
$$\lim_{y\to y_0}\left(\sup_{t\in E}|f_y(t)-g(t)|\right)=0.$$
In your example, you can easily derive it from the fact that $\lim_{s\to0}\frac{\sin s}s=1.$

Comment: For b, use that $0<g(t)-f_y(t)<g(t)$ and $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_R^\infty g=0.$

Comment: As for c, better ask it later (if necessary) in a separate post, where you will include your attempts.  [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) (and focus on one question per post).

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand parts (a) and (b) now. Really appreciate it!